# XamlParseException when using ExpressionDark in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, exception

I am currently using the ExpressionDark theme in a Silverlight project I am working on. I am having an issue where it throws an exception when I debug.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.dll

Additional information: Invalid attribute value dataForm:DataForm for property TargetType. [Line: 1 Position: 233]
```

This doesn't really affect anything because it still works fine, its just annoying. Here is a code example.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:expressionDark="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Theming;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Theming.ExpressionDark" 
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <expressionDark:ExpressionDarkTheme ApplyMode="Auto" Background="#00000000">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#00000000">
        </Grid>
    </expressionDark:ExpressionDarkTheme>
</UserControl>
```

If I comment out the expressionDark lines the exception goes away. Any idea on how to fix the exception or ignore it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needed reference has not been added for the `DataForm` within the consuming assembly.

Add a reference to the `System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm` assembly. If you need to make use of the `DataForm` within the `UserControl` explicitly you can define a namespace.

```
    xmlns:dataControls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;
assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I didn't have to add the namespace for the exceptions to go away. Should I include this anyway? I just added a Reference to System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit and that fixed it.

Comment: @thecaptain0220 No; you do not need to add the namespace; unless you are explicitly using it within the UserControl.